# Template is missing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning `Ruby-on-Rails`. For this I have a 'hello world' sample.
Thats my `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root 'application#show'
end
```

`controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def show
    render 'startpage'
  end
end
```

And finally my `views/startpage.html.erb`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>

<body id="index" class="home"><h1>Hello World!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open my site I get this error:

```
Template is missing
Missing template application/startpage with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"
```

So, am I missing something or has the `startpage.html.erb` file somewhere else?

Comment: move your views/startpage.html.erb file to views/application/startpage.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template would need to be inside of `/views/application` for the convention to work.

Rails looks inside of `/views/CONTROLLER/action` by convention without specifying a specific location.

`/views/application/startpage.html.erb` should work in your situation.

**Bonus learning points:**

A common practice I see for creating normal, static pages, is a `PagesController` which handles each of them. Doing this, your route would point to `pages#startpage` and your view would be inside of `/views/pages/startpage.html.erb` -- Just a tip!

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm able to. BTW: +1 for the tip, I'll try it!